# How can I create a new column in PySpark with Date_Sub and Agg functions?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a new column with date aggregations -- How can I include a date_sub along with MIN,MIX aggregations within the with column operator?

So far I have tried these methods -

```
.withColumn("Last_Year_START_Date", F.date_sub(date_sub("DayDate"),364))
```

```
.select(F.date_sub(min(col("DayDate")),1)364).alias('Last_Year_START_Date')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
.select(date_sub("DayDate", 364).alias('LY_YearStartDate'),"DayDate")
.agg(F.min("LY_YearStartDate").alias("LY_YearStartDate"))
```